# How to automatically execute shell script at startup boot on systemd Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: linux, systemd

I want setup shadowsocks antumatically start at startup on ubuntu 18.04

See [this](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-automatically-execute-shell-script-at-startup-boot-on-systemd-linux).

My shell is shadowsocks.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /usr/bin/sslocal ]; then 
   sudo /usr/bin/sslocal -c /etc/shadowsocks/config.json -d restart -v
fi
```

It runs well

and I setup with systemctl

like this shadowsocks.service

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/shadowsocks.sh
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
Alias=ss.service
```

when I run

```
sudo systemctl start ss.service
```

I can see shadowsocks logged "started"

but I can't see shadowsocks started and I can't use google.

I'm chinese, I'm sorry for my bad English, I wish someone can see my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete -d in shell script

everything is ok

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is via ubuntu tweaks tool. Just install tweak tool and add ur applicaiton via the GUI. Example

http://xtrace.blogspot.com/2020/02/run-script-at-startup-of-ubuntu.html